# How to enable Bing Spell check in LUIS API 2.0?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have created 2 resources on Azure, 1 is LUIS Authoring Resource and other is Cognitive Services resource. Then created a LUIS app and deployed it.

I'm trying to use the Bing Spell Check feature on the LUIS but it doesn't seem to work.

URL: `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/<APP_ID>?spellCheck=true&bing-spell-check-subscription-key=<KEY>&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=330&subscription-key=<KEY>&q=I%20hav%20not%20recieved%20statment`

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I tried using the above URL for my LUIS app and it worked just fine providing me with the alteredQuery. Are you getting any error when you try the above URL or it just comes back with the same query and intent JSON?

Comment: All I did was created a new Bing Spell Check resource on Azure, copied the key1 value from the Keys. Then I updated the URL `https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/{appID}?subscription-key={luisKey}&spellCheck=**true**&bing-spell-check-subscription-key=**{bingKey}**&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q={utterance}` with the corresponding region,appID, subscription-key from the LUIS portal for my app and the newly generated key1.

Comment: @ranusharao Thank you. I thought creating a Cognitive Resource would cover all the Language and Speech features but no. I had to create a separate spell check resource to get this working.

Comment: Glad that it helped.Just for reference for others: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bing-spellcheck

Comment: For each service on azure portal you have to integrate separate service on that [see the screen shot](https://imgur.com/a/JdwPrIz)